# What is a set of $r\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading a book called Mathematics for Computer Science. I don't understand what the authors mean by a set in the form rn where $r$ is a positive real number and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Does this simply mean a set where each element is a positive real number multiplied by a natural number?
[Picture of the notation used in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6W2S.png)

Answer (score 2):

No. Here $r$ is a *fixed* positive real number, and$$r\Bbb N=\{rn\mid n\in\Bbb N\}=\{0,r,2r,3r,4r,\ldots\}.$$

Comment: It appears that $0\in\mathbb{N}$ is assumed.

Comment: @user10354138 Indeed. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!